# What would be the increase of gravity if we create a new world slightly bigger than the earth?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, time, earth, geophysics

I need to know what would happen if I increased the earth's size by a small percentage to make a fictional world similar to earth. So my thought process is this: My thinking started with increasing the earth's time zones or to increase the number to time zones.

- At first I wanting to add 4 more hours making the planet to have 28 time zones all with 60 minutes per hour
- Then I decided to leave it at 24 hours at 70 minutes an hour.
- I calculated that it would be a 16.667% increase in time and distance between each time zone.
  My question is what would be the increase of gravity, and how would it affect the world we live it; people, animals, plant life, landmasses, etc.? Any details or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depends what the inside of the planet is made of. I imagine a scenario where a planet forms with huge pockets of gases inside thus actually making the gravity lighter over all. Other deposits could consist of dark matter could make an area of the planet heavier the closer you get to the deposit.

Comment: More over enough dark matter in the planet on one side would give the an oblong rotation or wobble in turn giving the sides of the planet less light that the side with the dark matter. This would really give you an odd time zone and weather pattern; of what is up to you.

Comment: The question is closed, thus I had to give my answer here. If you increase the size of the earth by keeping its mass-density, its mass would increase, and consequentially, the earth $g$-field would increase:

If you increase the Earth's radius ($r$) by a distance $h$ from the surface, the $g$-fields before and after this increase are calculated to be:

$$g=\frac{GM}{r^2}\space,$$

$$g'=\frac{GM'}{(r+h)^2}\space.$$

Since the densities are assumed to be the same, we have:

$$\rho=\frac{M}{4\pi r^3/3}=\rho'=\frac{M'}{4\pi (r+h)^3/3}\rightarrow$$

$$M'=\frac{(r+h)^3}{r^3}M\space$$ ...

Comment: Therefore, we have:

$$g'=\frac{GM'}{(r+h)^2}=\frac{GM(r+h)}{r^3}=\frac{GM}{r^2}+\frac{GMh}{r^3}\space.$$

Substituting the first equation implies:

$$g'=g+\frac{h}{r}g=g(1+\frac{h}{r})\space.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want more time in a day, you don't need a slightly bigger Earth, you need one that rotates slightly slower - which is trivial to do since the Earth's rotation is already slowing down thanks to tidal interactions with the Moon.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I feel you are missing the variables that I have requested. For example if you look at a time zone map of the earth the time zone lines have and equal distance apart. If you were to use the same rate in time and speed; 100 milliseconds= a second, 60 seconds equals a minute and so on... Using the time zone as a reference point for distance not time, and adding an addition 10 minutes per time zone (which equals an additional 240 hours added to the earth current rotation. How big would the earth be and affects would there be on us, animals, plant life, etc.?

Comment: @RichManoogianJr. I don't understand what you mean. Why would adding time to each timezone change the size of the Earth? It just means the Earth's rotation slowed down.